# How to get the attribute name on a model?

Tags: c#

How can i get the attibut's name on a model that i have created ?

For example for this case ID_HR, SURNAME, NAME
I tried whit GetProperties but it doesn't work

```
public class Person
{

    public string ID_HR;
    public string SURNAME;
    public string NAME;
    public string GENDER;
    public string N_GENDER;
    public DateTime? DT_BIRTH;
```

}

I TRIED THIS

```
 Type parent = typeof(VSM_Data);
            FieldInfo[] children = parent.GetFields();

            for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
            {

                Type child = children[i].GetType();

                var columnnamesChild = from t in child.GetProperties() select t.Name;
                foreach (var item in columnnamesChild)
                {
                    DragAndDrop FundDragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
                    FundDragAndDrop.TITLE = item;
                    FundDragAndDrop.adresse = "{{PERSON." + children[i].Name.ToUpper() + "." + item.ToUpper() + "}}";
                    FundList.Add(FundDragAndDrop);

                }
```

AND THIS

```
FieldInfo[] myPropertyInfo = children[i].GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public);

                for (int a = 0; a < myPropertyInfo.Length; a++)
                {
                    DragAndDrop FundDragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
                    FundDragAndDrop.TITLE = myPropertyInfo.ToString();
                    FundDragAndDrop.adresse = "{{PERSON." + children[i].Name.ToUpper() + "." + myPropertyInfo.ToString().ToUpper() + "}}";
                    FundList.Add(FundDragAndDrop);
                }
```

Comment: see about [GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's a class who there are class.. on this class i do have Person, Country class and i want to have all attibut name of this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you class `VMS_Data` something like this

```
class VMS_Data{
    ....
    Person p;
    Country c;
    ....
}
```

then when you do

```
Type child = children[i].GetType();
```

you try get type from `FieldInfo`. You need use [FieldType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead like this

```
Type child = children[i].FieldType;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because what you've declared are not properties, but simple member variables. `GetProperties` does not work with member variables. Use this to get properties:

```
public class Person
{

    public string ID_HR { get; set; }
    public string SURNAME { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string GENDER { get; set; }
    public string N_GENDER { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DT_BIRTH { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work i still have same variable "NAME, METADATATOKEN,FIELDHANDLE,ATTIBUTS...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your properties using `get` and `set` else it would be a `member variable` only. Try like this:

```
public class Person
{

    public string ID_HR { get; set; }
    public string SURNAME { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string GENDER { get; set; }
    public string N_GENDER { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DT_BIRTH { get; set; }
}
```

And then use the [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: @user3510152:- Can you update your question with what you have tried and what you are getting? When you say it is not working it is not understandable!

Comment: it's done  i still have same variable (NAME, METADATATOKEN,FIELDHANDLE,ATTIBUTS...)

Comment: @user3510152:- Have you done the changes to your Person class and set the properties as answered? And what is VMS_Data?

Comment: Yes i do now i do have the {get;set;} next to the attibutes